# Searchkick fuzzy matching specific fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm rebuilding a Ransack filter form into a Searchkick query now, but I'm having a hard time with the fuzzy matching.  Here's my setup:

```
# Company.rb
searchkick word_start: [:name]

def search_data
  {
    name: name,
  }
end
```

Running this returns zero results

```
Company.search("*", where: {name: "Te"}, fields: [{name: :word_start}])
```

`where: { name: "Test" }` works fine though.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Did you reindex your data after the changes? And also you may try this after reindex: `Company.search "te", fields: [:name], match: :word_start` (not sure if this will help).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Yeah I definitely reindexed, no luck.  Your example would most likely work but the problem is I'm going to be filtering like... 20 fields.  some are IDs, some are text.  Which is why I want to separate them out into the `where` clause so I can handle each one differently

Comment: Okay what if you do it like this: `Company.search("Te", fields: [{name: :word_start}])`

Comment: Yeah that totally works, but essentially what i need to do is: `Company.search("*", where: { name: "Te", status_id: 2, author: "Dave", ...}, fields: [{name: :word_start}, {author: :word_start}])`  Like if I write "Test" in an Author search field I don't want to find companies that start with "Test" - only Authors